# Can Ajax be used without using jquery? Or do I need jquery for ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know that AJAX makes the page more interactive and real time, but do I need jQuery if I would be using AJAX?

Comment: You don't need jQuery, but jQuery makes it easier. You can use XMLHttpRequests  directly. See the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Hardly any easier, unless you take all the IE6 fallbacks into account. If you go for modern browser support (IE8 or IE9 and above), you can just use `XMLHttpRequest` and you won't need browser-specific exceptions.

Comment: Given the context of your question, you might want to read: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ It shows native Javascript solutions for common problems that are (too?) often solved using jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is written in javascript. Therefore, anything jQuery can do can be done directly in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to jQuery in order to use AJAX. JavaScript has its own way.

Like this:

**Initialization**

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

**Request Sending**

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

You can learn more here about javascript ajax [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

Comment: I think by now we can skip the whole IE6- stuff and show how simple Ajax can actually be, even without jQuery.